# screen fills with object texture after creating user defined target(vuforia 4 unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I created this small demo where I am creating a user defined target. The model is generating fine on PC after creating the target. It works fine when I test it on PC (using webcam, image is attached)

[image]

but when I test it on my phone (Motog 2), after creating the user defined target it fills the screen with the texture that the object has.

[image]

It only shows the normal map. When I move the camera away from the image target the texture disappears.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your Image Target appears shiny. That could be problematic while detecting. But I really have no information from your side to help you out. Does the above image look like you're inside the object? Try making the object smaller and test it to see if you can see it?

Comment: tried with different targets and sizes ... anyways the problem has been solved.. I just changed the ARcamera's backgroundPanel's video material from custom/videoBackground to custom/renderedVideoBackground..

Comment: Oh okay. Please type down your answer so future solution seekers may be able to find this solution easier. If you do not wish to do so, I can write it down for you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem has been solved.. I just changed the ARcamera's backgroundPanel's video material from custom/videoBackground to custom/renderedVideoBackground.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a legacy shader on your object.... Use Unity's standard shader and your problem will be solved. This problem is only associated with Unity 5

Comment: thanks for your reply  .. I just changed the ARcamera's backgroundPanel's video material and the problem is solved